# Testing Automation on charts.js and angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

So I was writing a testing automation for charts.js and to retrieve the data I used the **ngContext** object like this:
`document.getElementsByTagName('chart-dataset')[0].__ngContext__`
But now after we upgraded to angular 14 **ngContext** is now an integer. Anyone knows whats going on? And where can I find the charts data if not in *ngContext*_?

EDIT:
I need to get the data from the client side. I don't have access to the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to do screenshot comparison
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the static [Chart.getChart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/developers/api.html#static-getchart-key) method:

```js
const chart = Chart.getChart(canvasId);
const data = chart.data.datasets[0].data;
```

Comment: Its undefined when I do Chart.getChart(document.querySelector('canvas'))

Comment: You need to pass the canvas id not a query selector

Comment: Where can I get the canvas id?

Comment: Where you make your chart

Comment: I don't have access to the code itself. I need to get the data from the client side.

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You could in your `document.getElementsByTagName('chart-dataset')` look for the canvas itself then get the id out of it and use my solution otherwise I dont know, hard to help since I don't know the exact structure of the code and how it works

Comment: Anyone knows of a way to do automated tests on charts.js?

Comment: You could do screenshot comparisons

Answer (score 0):

You can access the component's data using `ng.getComponent(document.getElementsByTagName('chart-dataset')[0])`

also, after running this code, ngContext becomes an object.